# Limit of a natural logs

Tags: limits

Find:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} (k^2-1)\ln(\frac{k-1}{k+1}) + 2k$$

I got the following:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} (k^2-1)\ln(\frac{k-1}{k+1}) + 2k$$
$$= -\infty + \infty$$

Using L'Hopitals theorem, the limit becomes:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2k \ln (\frac{k-1}{k+1}) + 4 $$
$$ = - \infty + 4 $$
$$ = - \infty $$

Using L'Hopitals theorem again:

$$\lim_{k \to \infty} 2 \ln (\frac{k-1}{k+1}) + \frac{4k}{(k-1)(k+1)} $$
$$ = 0 + \frac {\infty}{\infty}$$
$$= \frac {\infty}{\infty} $$
Using L'Hopital's theorem again:
$$\lim_{k \to \infty} \frac {-8}{(k-1)^2(k+1)^2}$$
$$= 0$$

I don't know if I did the limit correctly or if I made assumptions I am not allowed to make.

Comment: Excuse me, but $k\in\mathbb{N}$ or $k\in\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @Sebastiano Technically it doesn't matter; although we obviously cannot differentiate a sequence, the function is continuous so the limit as any sequence increases to infinity is the same as the limit as the function of $x\in\mathbb R$ increases to infinite.

Comment: For what it's worth, Mathematica confirms that the limit is indeed zero.

Comment: @Math1000 Hi; yes of course. But Hôpital's rule is not apply with a sequence.

Comment: We are not applying L'hopital's rule to the sequence, but rather to the function of a continuous variable associated with that sequence. The limits are equivalent because the function $$x\mapsto (x^2-1)\log\left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)+2x$$ is continuous (for large $x$).

Answer (score 1):

The final result is correct but we can't apply l'[Hospital's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule#Proof_of_L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule) in that way since we need to have indeterminate form $\frac{0}{0}$ nor $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ nor $\frac{c}{\infty}$.

By second order expansion we have that

$$\ln\left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right)=\ln\left(1-\frac{2}{k+1}\right)=-\frac{2}{k+1}-\frac{2}{(k+1)^2}+O\left(\frac1{k^3}\right)$$

and therefore

$$(k^2-1)\ln\left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right) + 2k=-\frac{2(k+1)(k-1)}{k+1}-\frac{2(k+1)(k-1)}{(k+1)^2}+2k+O\left(\frac1{k}\right)=$$

$$=2-\frac{2(k+1)(k-1)}{(k+1)^2}+O\left(\frac1{k}\right) \to 0$$

To apply l'Hospital we need to manipilate the original expression as follows

$$(k^2-1)\ln\left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right) + 2k=\frac{\ln\left(\frac{k-1}{k+1}\right)+\frac{2k}{k^2-1}}{\frac1{k^2-1}}$$

which is in the form $\frac 0 0$ then by l'Hospital we obtain

$$\frac{\frac{2}{k^2-1}-\frac{2(k^2+1)}{(k^2-1)^2}}{-\frac{2k}{(k^2-1)^2}}=\frac{-\frac{4}{(k^2-1)^2}}{-\frac{2k}{(k^2-1)^2}}=\frac 2k \to 0$$

Answer (score 0):

You cant apply l'Hopital to the original expression.  Let $x=\frac{1}{k}$, so you have

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{(1-x^2)\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)+ 2x}{x^2}.
$$

Apply l'Hopital to get

$$
\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{-2x \ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)}{2x} =\lim_{x\to 0}\left(-\ln\left(\frac{1-x}{1+x}\right)\right)=0.
$$